# Laravel - querying polymorphic relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have tables `content`, `taxonomies`, `content_taxonomies` and `content_types`. Their relationships are set up like this:

**Content** model:

```
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\ContentTaxonomy', 'taxonomical');
}
```

**Taxonomy** model:

```
public function content()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Content', 'App\ContentTaxonomy');
}
```

**ContentTaxonomy** model:

```
public function content()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Content', 'taxonomical');
}

public function term()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Taxonomy', 'id', 'taxonomy_id');
}
```

**ContentType** model:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'ct_id');
}
```

**taxonomies** table has this columns with a record example:

```
id | tt_id |    slug    |     name
       1     prevensjon    Prevensjon
```

**content_taxonomies** has columns with a record example:

```
id | taxonomy_id | taxonomical_id | taxonomical_type
           1             1               App\Content
```

**content_types** has columns with a record example:

```
id | name | slug
     post   post
```

I have a route with 2 optional arguments, for example `prevensjon/prosjektsamarbeidets-verdi` where the first argument is `taxonomy slug`, and the second argument is the slug of the `content`.
I need to make the query, where I would have to find the `content` that has the `content_type` with the slug `post` or `page` and that also belongs to `taxonomy` with the `slug` of `prevensjon` and that has itself the same slug as `prosjektsamarbeidets-verdi`. 
So far I am fetching `content` that has the `content type` where the `slug` is equal to `post` and where the `content` `slug` is equal to the `slug` that I am sending which is in this case `prosjektsamarbeidets-verdi`.

```
$content = Content::whereHas('contentType', function ($query) {
                      $query->where('slug', 'post');
                    })
                    ->where('slug', $arguments['slug'])
                    ->with('supplementary')
                    ->first();
```

But, not sure how to do expand this query so that I can check further if the content has the `taxonomy` with the same `slug` that I am sending as an `argument` which is in this case `prevensjon`?